# How to share information between two client components in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-server-components

I have two client components inside a server component. It is a date selector and a scoreboard that shows scores on that date. However, I do not want to have them in the same client component as I want them to be rendered in different parts of the UI. The scoreboard component needs the date to determine which scores are shown, so I am using useState. Is there anyway I can set useState for a client component from a different client component or what is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I think "Lifting the state up" is the thing you're looking for. In short, you will place the useState on closest parent of both your components, and pass them down to each component.

This is documented by React on [their own document](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components).

Comment: Yes but I would prefer not to do this because then the parent component would be made a client component as well

Comment: @ZachSal why do you want to keep the parent component a server component?

Comment: You've taken a difficult but relevant question, and rather than come and say "sorry but it's just not possible," you've chosen to ignore it and answer an easier question.

There are very good reasons why you might want to keep the parent component a server component. I'm not the OP, but in my case it's because the page is generated from a very large data object that I don't want the user to have to download.

Comment: @MarkVerrey I ask for the root problem just to clarify what's needed, and what's the other options we can offer. You've already proven that "it's possible" in your answer. Don't know why you need to be passive aggressive with other answers that is not good as yours.

Comment: @ngtrthinh I got angry because I was looking for a solution and saw your comment. I then thought about it for an hour and came up with a solution, which I provided here.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to keep shareable values in `context` and consume in the components.

[zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand) also good alternative to do state management and share values between components. A small, fast and scalable bearbones state-management solution using simplified flux principles. Has a comfy API based on hooks, isn't boilerplatey or opinionated

Comment: Like the other responder, you've also missed that the question was specifically about a nextjs server component. Context is only available on client components, so both solutions, context or state lifting, can only work if they wrap the client components inside another client component, which they've said they don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an answer: [Passing Server Components to Client Components as Props](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#supported-pattern-passing-server-components-to-client-components-as-props)

You aren't limited to just using the `children` prop, you can pass server components as any named property you want. So you can use other posters' suggestions of lifting the state or using context, by creating a client-side layout control that takes all the server-side headers, footers, etc. as parameters, and still have them all generated on the server. This would look something like:

```
import { MyServerGeneratedHeader } from './my-server-generated-header';
import { MyServerGeneratedFooter } from './my-server-generated-footer';
import { MyClientSideFrame } from './my-client-side-frame';

export default function Page() {
  const serverGeneratedHeader = <MyServerGeneratedHeader />;
  const serverGeneratedFooter = <MyServerGeneratedFooter />;

  return (
    <MyClientSideFrame
      Header={serverGeneratedHeader}
      Footer={serverGeneratedFooter}
    />
  );
}
```

And then in my-client-side-frame.jsx:

```
'use client'
import { useState } from 'react';
import { MyDatePicker } from './my-date-picker';
import { MyScoreBoard } from './my-score-board';

export default function MyClientSideFrame({ Header, Footer }) {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(Date.UTCNow());

  function handleDateChange(d => {
    setDate(d);
  }

  return (<>
    <Header />
    <MyDatePicker onDateChange={handleDateChange} />
    <MyScoreBoard date={date} />
    <Footer />
  </>);
}
```

And now your header and footer will be generated on the server while you can still use state to tie your date selector to your scoreboard.